# Custom actions in cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I have cancan working fine for everything except custom actions. I had an upload_photos action that just wasn't being secured correctly. I added a test action which was really basic that looked like this in the ability.rb file:

```
can :test, User, :id => user.id
```

but for some reason it always evaluated to true so I changed it to the following

```
can :test, User, :email => 'a@a.com'
```

and again it always evaluates to true.

Anybody know why cancan isn't working correctly here?

My users controller has the following at the top:

```
load_and_authorize_resource
```

Thanks in advance.

**SOLUTION:**

Cancan's load_and_authorize_resource interferes with custom actions so we need to do something like

```
load_and_authorize_resource :except => [:test]
```

and then in the test action:

```
authorize! :test, @user
```